# Why Won't My PHP Program Show a Table's Data Properly or at All?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

---PHP/MySQL/Javascript/ Question---

This is basically my attempt to modify to tutorial online to suit my needs, as I'm very new to all three languages that are being used here, so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm trying to create a sortable table that can re-sort the contents without reloading the page by clicking the buttons that represent the various column headers.  So far, only two of my five column-buttons will show anything, but it's broken (though it properly sorts ascending and descending without reloading, so there's that), so clearly I need to fix how it's formatted. Example:

```
Larry/div>
Fitzgerald/div>
WR/div>
Ari/div>
19
Chandler/div>
Caranzaro/div>
K/div>
Ari/div>
6
```

All in the first column instead of separating the data out to the proper columns.

Oddly enough, the column-buttons that won't show any data are the ones that have underscores in their names.  I don't know if that's coincidence or if it makes a difference.  The columns are as follows: first_name, last_name, position, team, average_score.  The "position" and "team" buttons work insofar as actually showing data.  The other three draw blanks.

To summarize: How can I fix my formatting error and get the other three column-buttons to show data?

Here's the code section that is supposed to populate the table.

```
<?php
//Connecting to MYSQL Database
$database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//Populating the table with data from database
if (isset($_POST['sorter'])) {
   $userlist = "";
   $sorter = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['sorter']);
   $array = explode(".", $sorter);
   $sql = 'SELECT first_name, last_name, position, team, average_score FROM players_with_average_scores ORDER BY '.$array[0].' '.$array[1];
   $query = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
      $userlist .= '<div class="txt">'.$row[0].'/div><div class="txt">'.$row[1].'/div><div class="txt">'.$row[2].'/div><div class="txt">'.$row[3].'/div><div class="txt">'.$row[4].'</div>';
   }
echo $userlist;
exit();
}
?>
```

Beyond that, here's the section of code that is supposed to change how to data is sorted, in case that's where the problem is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sortBy(btn) {
   var a = btn.split(".");
   var b = "";
   //Switches from ascending to descending or vice-versa depending on the current selection.
   (a[1] == "ASC") ? b = "DESC" : b = "ASC";
   var c = a[0]+"."+b;
   document.getElementById(btn).id = c;
   document.getElementById("uList").innerHTML = 'One moment please...';

   var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "test.php";
   hr.open("POST", url, true);
   hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
         var return_data = hr.responseText;
         document.getElementById("uList").innerHTML = return_data;
      }
  }
   hr.send("sorter="+btn);
}
```

There's also the part of the file where I make the buttons and designate a section to be the data, in the event that that's what's incorrect:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="title"><h1>Potential Employee Evaluation Test</h1></div>
   <div id="btns">
      <button class="txt" id="first_name.ASC" onClick="sortBy(this.id)">first_name</button>
      <button class="txt" id="last_name.ASC" onClick="sortBy(this.id)">last_name</button>
      <button class="txt" id="position.ASC" onClick="sortBy(this.id)">position</button>
      <button class="txt" id="team.ASC" onClick="sortBy(this.id)">team</button>
      <button class="txt" id="average_score.ASC" onClick="sortBy(this.id)">average_score</button>
   </div>
   <div id="uList"></div>
</div>
```

If there's anything else you need, please do let me know.

Much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to Phiter Fernandes, I've been able to correct the output problem for the data for the column-buttons that actually work.  Now my only problem is that the other column-buttons still don't show any data at all when pressed.

EDIT 2: I discovered the problem, but I have no idea why it's a problem in the first place.  The underscores I mentioned earlier were the collective culprit.  I redid my database to where the column names would not have underscores, changed my .php file to match that change, and everything now works superbly.  I thank everyone who helped.

Comment: First thing I saw is that you're not closing your divs properly at `<div class="txt">'.$row[0].'/div>`

Comment: Also this ternary is wrong  `(a[1] == "ASC") ? b = "DESC" : b = "ASC";`, should be `b = (a[1] == "ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";`

Comment: Also you have the jQuery tag but you're not using it anywhere, and for what you're doing, jQuery would ease a lot of stuff. You're also trying to sort divs, which is weird. If your data is supposed to show up like a table, use the table element for it.

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you.  I feel incredibly silly for not noticing how many divs I didn't close.  I still can't figure out why my other buttons won't show any data, though.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: I have. There are no errors.  The webpage shows up perfectly -- it's just that the table in it isn't acting quite how I'd like.